# Sql Window function on whole dataframe in spark

Tags: spark-streaming, sql-function

I am working on spark streaming project which consumes data from Kafka in every 3 minutes. I want to calculate moving sum of value. Below is the sample logic for a rdd which works well. I want to know will this logic work for spark streaming. I read some docs that you have to assign rang of data.  ex -  `Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(-1, 1)` But I want to calculate the logic on whole dataframe. Does the below logic work for the whole value of dataframe or It will take only the range of value of dataframe.

```
val customers = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("Alice", "2016-05-01", 50.00),
  ("Alice", "2016-05-03", 45.00),
  ("Alice", "2016-05-04", 55.00),
  ("Bob", "2016-05-01", 25.00),
  ("Bob", "2016-05-04", 29.00),
  ("Bob", "2016-05-06", 27.00))).
  toDF("name", "date", "amountSpent")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val wSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date")
customers.withColumn( "movingSum",
  sum(customers("amountSpent")).over(wSpec1)  ).show()
```

output

```
    +-----+----------+-----------+---------+
    | name|      date|amountSpent|movingSum|
    +-----+----------+-----------+---------+
    |  Bob|2016-05-01|       25.0|     25.0|
    |  Bob|2016-05-04|       29.0|     54.0|
    |  Bob|2016-05-06|       27.0|     81.0|
    |Alice|2016-05-01|       50.0|     50.0|
    |Alice|2016-05-03|       45.0|     95.0|
    |Alice|2016-05-04|       55.0|    150.0|
    +-----+----------+-----------+---------+
```